# Prevent user from clicking button multiple times

Tags: asp.net, forms, button, onclick

I'm editing code in ASP and need help fixing this code so that the user can only submit the form once (prevent duplicate submissions):

Code I have is:

```
<asp:button id="btnSave" runat="server" onclick="btnSave_Click" text="Submit" />
```

How to I change `onclick` to allow only one submission?

Comment: This is not Classic ASP - it's ASP.NET. Please retag and you may get more responses.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to disable the button after it is pressed the first time.

```
Sub btnSave_Click

   btnSave.Enabled = false

End Sub
```

But then you will need to set `Enabled = true` again, when appropriate for the user to submit again.

You may need to implement this is Java so that the form does not wait for the run around between the Browser and Server.  Using code similar to this wrapped in a Java function

```
document.getElementById('btnSave').Enabled = false
```